# How can I put a different color for each icon in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I put a different color for each icon in this code:

```
    {'name': 'Open', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'folder_open'},
    {'name': 'New', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'add_circle'},
    {'name': 'Delete', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'delete'},
    {'name': 'Edit', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'edit'},
  ]
```

The full code here:

```
interface Page {
  link: string;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-left-buttons-tree-view',
  templateUrl: './left-buttons-tree-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-buttons-tree-view.component.css'],
  animations: [onSideNavChange, animateText]
})

export class LeftButtonsTreeViewComponent implements OnInit {


  public sideNavState: boolean = false;
  public linkText: boolean = false;

  public pages: Page[] = [
    {'name': 'Open', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'folder_open'},
    {'name': 'New', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'add_circle'},
    {'name': 'Delete', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'delete'},
    {'name': 'Edit', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'edit'},
  ]
```

Later Edit this is HTML code:

```
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" style="height: 100%;">
    
        <div>
          <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
              <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
              <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
            </a>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onSinenavToggle()">
          <mat-icon *ngIf="sideNavState">arrow_left</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="!sideNavState">arrow_right</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```adding color```? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Can I see you Html template?

Comment: @Drag13  For example: I want the color for 'folder_open ' to be yellow , for 'add_circle' to be green, for 'delete' to be red etc.

Comment: @PavelB.
<div class="sidenav_container"  [@onSideNavChange]="sideNavState ? 'open' : 'close'">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" style="height: 100%;">
        <mat-nav-list>
          <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
            <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
            <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
          </a>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: @RoxanneL don't you have already answer to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seing your html I suppose you are using some icon kit like font awesome or angular material icons etc. The icons use webfonts so you can change color of it any time. Just add a new color property to your array and set font color to it.

array modification

```
{'name': 'Open', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'folder_open', color:"#451278"},
{'name': 'New', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'add_circle', color:"#457878"},
{'name': 'Delete', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'delete'  color:"#651278"},
{'name': 'Edit', link:'some-link', 'icon': 'edit'  color:"#451248"}
```

HTML

```
<icon [style.color]="item.color">
```

Where item is the current item from the array